# Using `rank` on a pandas DataFrameGroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas

I have some simple data in a dataframe consisting of three columns [id, country, volume] where the index is 'id'.

I can perform simple operations like:

```
df_vol.groupby('country').sum()
```

and it works as expected.  When I attempt to use rank() it does not work as expected and the results is an empty dataframe.

```
df_vol.groupby('country').rank()
```

The result is not consistent and in some cases it works. The following also works as expected:

```
df_vol.rank()
```

I want to return something like:

```
vols = []
for _, df in f_vol.groupby('country'):
    vols.append(df['volume'].rank())
pd.concat(vols)
```

Any ideas why much appreciated!

Comment: guess I can make it slightly tider using list comprehension but still curious as to why it does no work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add column by `[]` - function is call only for column `Volume`:

```
df_vol.groupby('country')['volume'].rank()
```

Sample:

```
df_vol = pd.DataFrame({'country':['en','us','us','en','en'],
                   'volume':[10,10,30,20,50],
                   'id':[1,1,1,2,2]})
print(df_vol)
  country  id  volume
0      en   1      10
1      us   1      10
2      us   1      30
3      en   2      20
4      en   2      50

df_vol['r'] = df_vol.groupby('country')['volume'].rank()
print (df_vol)
  country  id  volume    r
0      en   1      10  1.0
1      us   1      10  1.0
2      us   1      30  2.0
3      en   2      20  2.0
4      en   2      50  3.0
```

Comment: Actually this still does not work and I get a value error originating from the wrapper() function in groupby.py.  rank() still works as expected on the single column.

Comment: Hmmm, problem in data? Data are numeric?

Comment: All numeric and rank works fine on ungrouped dataset.  All numeric but very large numbers.

Comment: Is possible send me your csv file for test? My email is in my profile. Because it seem it is data dependent.